# Rendering of Google Markers is relatively slow in IE7

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Google Map loads the Markers very slow and it load all the markers at one go. Suppose my application loads 600+ markers, it is relatively slow in IE7 when compared to Firefox.

Do any one have any suggestions regarding this?

Comment: I'm going to take a guess and say there's not much you can do. The javascript engine in IE7/8 is... severely lacking, performance-wise.

Comment: IE7 is a slower browser compared to firefox. Deal with it. FF5/6 is probably about 1000 times faster then IE7

Comment: Yep. *everything* is relatively slow in IE7. Be surprised by this you should not. (and frankly, people who are still using IE7 will by now be used to things being slow, so I wouldn't get hung up about it)

Comment: Someone at my work was commenting on this some weeks ago when we were discussing some such things. And clustering markers is not reasonable for us due to what we do. And we use it mainly inside our application, so without significant effort which hasn't yet been justified (and is unlikely to be) we're stuck with using MSHTML...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clustering markers (grouping them). There are several ways to achieve this (google for it), but if the client is your bottleneck you could try doing it on the server...

Comment: If you have more Google Maps questions, consider getting advice at gis.stackexchange.com ...